# Install ubuntu on a macbook running windows 7

Tags: system-installation, windows, mac, macbook

I have an old macbook pro (from around 2005 I think) and it is running Windows 7 instead of OS X.

I want to install ubuntu but I don't even know where to start. I have installed ubuntu before, so I'm familiar with the process in normal pc's, but I know **nothing** about mac.

My main concerns are:

- Is making a bootable usb for mac different that for normal pc's? (keep in mind that it's running windows, not OS X)
- How do I boot into the live usb? In pc's, you access the BIOS by pressing `del` or one of the `f` keys. What do you do in a mac?

Comment: The OS currently installed doesn't (normally) affect what will happen when you install ubuntu. It also depends if you want to dual boot or not. So, you can follow the tutorial here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick